# append and join in separate rows using python

Tags: python

I need to join several append values. Tried as follows

```
     lines1.append(resnum[i])
     lines1.append(resname[i])
     lines1.append(resnum[j])
     lines1.append(resname[j])
     lines1.append(j-i)
     lines1.append(r1)
     s1 = '  '.join(map(str,lines1))
     print s1
     sv = open("1.out","w")
     sv.write('  '.join(map(str,lines1)))
     sv.close()
```

But it is printing everything in one line as follows.

```
     1  AAA  2  BBB  1  3.83433240604  2  AAA  3  BBB  1  3.82626841714  3  AAA  4  BBB  1  3.82807980586  4  AAA  5  BBB  1  3.86017836375  5  AAA  6  BBB  1  3.83235241073  6  AAA  7  BBB 3.76532115
```

If I try to use following.

```
     sv.write('\n'.join(map(str,lines1)))
```

I get the output as follows.

```
     1
     AAA
     2
     BBB
     1
     3.83433240604
     ..........
     ..........
```

How to get the output as follows

```
     1     AAA      2      BBB      1      3.83433240604
     2     AAA      3      BBB      1      3.83433240604
     ...................................................
     ...................................................
```

Comment: Could you provide the whole code you are using (with the loop)?

Comment: I just added the whole code in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked for me.

```
     sv1 = open('1.out','w')
     sv1.write( ("%s     %s      %s      %s      %s      %s\n") % (resnum[i], resname[i], resnum[j], resname[j], (j-i),r1))
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I'll explain my reasoning, and we can see where we diverge. I can't really use the above code unless I have a file sample because you have a lot of conditionals.

This is my interpretation of what your data looks like as the point where you are about to organize your computed data:

```
resname = ['ZZZ','AAA','BBB']
resnum = [0,1,2]
i = 1
j = 2
r1 = 3.1415926
```

So one line of your desired printout could be:

```
lines1 = [resnum[i], resname[i], resnum[j], resname[j], j-1, r1]
```

Maybe modify your code so that it goes something like:

```
for i in range(0,len(x)):
    all_lines = []
    for j in range(i+1,len(x)):
        lines1 = [resnum[i], resname[i], resnum[j], resname[j], j-1, r1]
        s1 = '  '.join(map(str,lines1))
        all_lines.append(s1)

with open('yourfile.txt', 'w') as f:
    for line in all_lines:
        f.write(line+'\n')
```

Try this one?

Answer (score 0):

You want a list of lists, not a singular list. 
Change this:

```
          lines1.append(resnum[i])
          lines1.append(resname[i])
          lines1.append(resnum[j])
          lines1.append(resname[j])
          lines1.append(j-i)
          lines1.append(r1)
```

Into this:

```
          interim = []
          interim.append(resnum[i])
          interim.append(resname[i])
          interim.append(resnum[j])
          interim.append(resname[j])
          interim.append(j-i)
          interim.append(r1)
          lines1.append(interim)
```

Comment: No its not helpful yet. When I print "lines1" I get everything in one line only.